# Saving PDF Curl response on server directory

Tags: php, api, pdf, curl, server-side

I'm getting and downloading a .pdf from an URL. It's downloading directly on my PC through the Curl request.
 How to save this in a directory at the server where the page is running?

I'm able to use PHP and JS, i've tried many things even combine the two languages but it seems only works the curl request, and it doesnt save that in the directory

```
<body>
    <button id="boton">CLICK ME</button>
        <?php
    $name = 'file'; 
    $file_downloaded = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($file_downloaded, CURLOPT_URL, 'The url'); 
    //curl_setopt($file_downloaded, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($file_downloaded, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($file_downloaded, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($file_downloaded, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    $file_downloaded = curl_exec($file_downloaded); 
    if(!curl_errno($file_downloaded)) 
    {
      header('Content-type:application/pdf'); 
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename ="'.$nuevo_nombre.'.pdf"'); 
      echo($file_downloaded);
      exit();
    }else
    {
      echo(curl_error($file_downloaded)); 
    }
    ?>

    <script>
        $("#boton").click(function () { 
        var archivo = '<?php echo($file_downlaoded) ?>';
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("data" , archivo);
        var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new activeXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        xhr.open( 'post', '/my/directory', true );
        xhr.send(data);
    });

    </script>
</body>
```

It's downloading on my local PC, and it's expected to download on the path /my/directory of the server.

## EDIT

```
        <?php
    $nuevo_nombre = 'remito'; //asignamos nuevo nombre
    $archivo_descarga = curl_init(); //inicializamos el curl
    curl_setopt($archivo_descarga, CURLOPT_URL, 'URL'); 
    //curl_setopt($archivo_descarga, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($archivo_descarga, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($archivo_descarga, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($archivo_descarga, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    $resultado_descarga = curl_exec($archivo_descarga); 
    file_put_contents('/path/to/file.pdf', $resultado_descarga);
?>
```

Comment: Just save the response: `file_put_contents('/path/to/file.pdf', $file_downloaded);`. If you don't want the file to be downloaded to the client at all, then remove all the `header()`'s and the `echo`.

Comment: However, I don't see how your code could work at all since you store the cURL resource (from `curl_init()`) in the variable `$file_downloaded` but are passing an undefined variable `$archivo_descarga` to all the `curl_setopt()`-calls.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I've editted the code, but when i get into the file, the php isn't saving the response

Comment: I hope you changed `/path/to/file.pdf` to a proper path on your server where PHP has write access?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It has been solved with file_putcontents() such as you say. There was also a permissions issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was solved with the file_put_contents() function, and there was also an issue with permissions on the directory folder.

```
function Download($endpoint) {
        $URL = 'URL';
        $fileName= 'name1';
        $path = 'testDirectory/'.$filename.'.pdf';
        $file_download= curl_init();

        curl_setopt($file__download, CURLOPT_URL, $URL.$endpoint);
        curl_setopt($file__download, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($file__download, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($file__download, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        $result= curl_exec($file__download);
        file_put_contents($path, $result);
}
```